# Get the name of class inheriting from base class in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have the following base class

```
class BaseClass
{
//Want to get the name of class A only, even if B is inherited from A
}

class A : BaseClass
{
}

class B : A
{
}
```

Can someone help me with getting the name of class A only from the base class.

Thanks

Comment: how are you trying to get that??

Comment: This is likey going to require reflection or saving the name in the constructor of A to a varable declared in BaseClass.

Comment: Would you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: typeof(BaseClass).Name gives base class only, and i know its wrong.

Comment: Not clear what you want, but in a non-static method/accessor in `BaseClass` you can use `var name = GetType().Name;` to get the name of the run-time type of this instance.

Comment: ... which will give you the `Name` of the type you have instantiated, which is not guaranteed to be `A`.

Comment: @HristoYankov Yeah, I do not think I understand the requirement. Does he need the type just "below" `BaseClass` no matter how deep the inheritance chain is? He could call `.BaseType` in a loop until he comes up to `typeof(BaseClass)` and use the name of the penultimate base type.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, apparently he wants to find the direct inheritor of his base class... from the base class. Yes, regardless of how deep the chain is, he is interested in the direct inheritor (I smell a bad design here).

Comment: Something like this, yes? `var type = this.GetType();  
     while (type != typeof(BaseClass))
     {
         type = this.GetType().BaseType;
     }
     return type.Name;`

Comment: @HristoYankov Maybe closer to this: `public string Name
{
  get
  {
    Type t = GetType();
    Type s = null;

    while (t != typeof(BaseClass))
    {
      s = t;
      t = t.BaseType;
    }

    return s?.Name;
  }
}` But otherwise yes.

Answer (score 3):

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
  public void GetInheritorName()
  {
    var nameIs = this.InheritorTellMeYourName();
  }

  protected abstract string InheritorTellMeYourName();
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
  protected sealed override string InheritorTellMeYourName()
  {
     return typeof(A).Name;
  }
}

public class B : A
{
}
```

Like someone mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't usually need anything like that...

Comment: One scenario I could think of would be custom serialization that needs to store the classname of the object being serialized.

Comment: @Satyajit I made an edit on the answer. Sorry! I meant `abstract`, not `virtual`!

Comment: You should make the override sealed, so `B` cannot override it differently.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense

Comment: This leaves a lot of opportunity for an inheriting class to not do what you want, through malice or accident.

Comment: That's true. I am thinking of a way to tighten it, but I can't. Natively to .NET, base classes don't know anything about the derived ones.